# Select all checkboxes in a specific scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
 $(".all_checkboxes").click(function () {
     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
 });
```

```css
td, th{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Section 1:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="all_checkboxes" /></th>
        <th>Names</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>instagram</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h2>Section 2:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="all_checkboxes" /></th>
        <th>Ids</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>454756</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>547498</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My question is almost clear in the fiddle above. As you can see, currently all checkboxes will be selected in both sections. All I need to do is define a scope for jQuery selector. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

`$('input:checkbox')` will search for all the checkboxes. You will have to navigate to closest `table` and search checkboxes in it.

```js
$(".all_checkboxes").click(function () {
     $(this)
      .closest('table')
      .find('input:checkbox')
      .not(this)
      .prop('checked', this.checked);
 });
```

```css
td, th{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Section 1:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="all_checkboxes" /></th>
        <th>Names</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>instagram</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h2>Section 2:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="all_checkboxes" /></th>
        <th>Ids</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>454756</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>547498</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want with in table. Use `closest()` to get the checkbox with in table
2. Use change event instead of click.

```js
$(".all_checkboxes").change(function () {
     $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
 });
```

```css
td, th{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Section 1:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="all_checkboxes" /></th>
        <th>Names</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>instagram</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h2>Section 2:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" class="all_checkboxes" /></th>
        <th>Ids</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>454756</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>547498</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is going to be a repeated action so you should consider having a faster solution than the ones available with jQuery.

Also your markup is not very well prepared for these kinds of actions. If updating the markup is an option. You can go as follows:

```
<h2>Section 1:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" data-checkall="names" class="all_checkboxes" /></th>
        <th>Names</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-rel="names" /></td>
        <td>twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-rel="names" /></td>
        <td>instagram</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h2>Section 2:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" data-checkall="section" class="all_checkboxes" /></th>
        <th>Ids</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-rel="section" /></td>
        <td>454756</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-rel="section" /></td>
        <td>547498</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Native JS version (fastest performance):

```
function checkAllHandler(e){
  var state = this.checked;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("[data-rel=" + this.dataset.checkall+"]"),
    function(x){
      x.checked = state;
    }
  )
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".all_checkboxes"), function(x){
  x.addEventListener("click", checkAllHandler);
})
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Mchaov/pen/vexprr?editors=1010